# How can I debug system processes through Android Studio?

Tags: android, debugging, android-source, aidl

I'd like to be able to step through the code that is run when my application calls out to a system process through an IBinder, (specifically the call to IWindowSession's relayout in ViewRootImpl), just for the sake of exploring the layout process.

I started by building AOSP to my device, but what would the next steps be? How can I add the AOSP sources and attach the debugger to whichever service is being communicated with by this IBinder?

Advice on how to accomplish this with Android Studio would be appreciated.